Logistic regression, natural log transformed continuous IV, interaction and RCS and plotting OR as function of continuous IV
I am working on a differential exposure effect analysis on a binary outcome in a logistic regression model.
My model parameters include:
    Binary outcome (y)
    Main binary exposure (x)
    One other continuous independent variable (a)
    Binary covariate(b)
    Binary covariate(c)

Covariate 'a' is a marker I am interested in assessing as an effect modifier of my binary exposure.
Some final additional information: I am unsure of the true form of the interaction, so I am using restricted cubic splines with my effect modifier and using 4 knots after some consideration.
If coding this in R, my model is:
     mod1=glm(y~x*rcs(a,4)+b+c,data=myDataset, family=binomial(link="logit"))

and then I use the chunk test to test for overall interaction across my three interaction and spline terms.
My final exercise is also, via the contrast package, estimating the differential treatment effect, post-model fit, across a plausible range of biomarker 'a' values, and plot this effect as a function of biomarker 'a'.
Range of biomarker 'a' values
      a_val=seq(1,1000, length=200)

So, something like this:
      rms::contrast(list(x=1,a=a_val,b=1,c=1), list(x=0,a=a_val,b=1,c=1)) 

and then I plot the effect of x (exponentiate, etc to get OR (95% CI)) across all values of a_val in my next step (not shown but very nice, smoothed curve was shown).
I additionally checked linearity of my marker 'a' in the adjusted model without an interaction term in a component+residual plot and post-checks and some additional consideration decided to natural log transform my marker 'a' in my above model to better handle several extreme values in my right tail. I refit with the only difference from above being marker 'a' was natural log transformed and replot again.
My one probably very simple question is this: when I am re-estimating my contrast using the same exact above model with natural log transformed covariate 'a', instead of natural 'a':
    rms::contrast(list(x=1,a=a_val,b=1,c=1),list(x=0,a=a_val,b=1,c=1)) 

***Should my a_val sequence also be on a natural log scale, too? In other words, when I estimate my exposure contrast, would the a_val sequence also be natural log transformed? I thought I was okay to also use a_val in the natural scale, and then after I estimate my exposure effect (exponentiate my log OR) I can plot using a natural log scale on the axes (one for OR (95% CI) and one for range of a_val).
Someone suggested, however, that since my second model utilized covariate 'a' on the natural log space I should also natural log transform the values for a_val in my contrast statement and then replot.  When I utilized their suggestion, though, the plot didn't really make sense to me and I think my original intuition was correct. I can't seem to quantitatively rationalize my approach relative to their suggestion, however, and any assistance would be great.***
Thank you again.
